# Can anyone point me to a working code or complete concept tut for ViewMetadata in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

I am trying to comprehend and link the concepts of viewmetadata and the basic usage for `encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation` , `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` , and `ViewEncapsulation.None` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewMetadata-class.html . Can anyone point me to difference of two options cleanly and working code for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewEncapsulation.None`:
No Shadow DOM at all. Therefore, also no style encapsulation.

`ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`:
No Shadow DOM but style encapsulation emulation.

`ViewEncapsulation.Native`:
Native Shadow DOM with all it’s goodness.

You got a well explained blog post with code samples here:
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.